# LINQ to SQL - Is it possible to make generic DB calls with similar tables?

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, generic-programming

In a C# application in which I am using **LINQ to SQL** (not Entity Framework) I have a schema with 2 different database tables that all have in common 1 column - "Language" which is a `string` and specifies a language such as "English", "German", etc.

For each English-language entity in these 2 tables, I have to make an identical copy of it except with a different value of "language". Let's say for this example I have two tables, `Articles` and `Editorials`. Thus, I have 2 **very similar** functions written like this:

```
private void CreateArticles()
{
    var englishEntities = DbContext.Articles.ToList();

    foreach (var englishEntity in englishEntities)
    {
        //for each english entity, create a copy of it in all languages
        foreach (string lang in LanguageList)
        {
            var newEntity = englishEntity;
            newEntity.Language = lang;

            DbContext.Articles.InsertOnSubmit(newEntity);
            DbContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}

private void CreateEditorials()
{
    var englishEntities = DbContext.Editorials.ToList();

    foreach (var englishEntity in englishEntities)
    {
        //for each english entity, create a copy of it in all languages
        foreach (string lang in LanguageList)
        {
            var newEntity = englishEntity;
            newEntity.Language = lang;

            DbContext.Editorials.InsertOnSubmit(newEntity);
            DbContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the **two functions are identical except** for the DB table that is retrieved from and saved into.

Since the only thing that I need to assign is `Language` which is a common column between the two tables, is there any way that I can combine these two functions into a function?

Answer (score 0):

First step could be:

```
private void Create<T>(DbSet<T> entities) where T: ILanguageEntity
{

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        foreach (string lang in LanguageList)
        {
            var newEntity = entity;
            newEntity.Language = lang;

            entities.Add(newEntity);

        }
    }
}
```

The call could look like:

```
   public void CallTheMethod {
        Create<Articles>(DbContext.Articles);
        DbContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Where is `DbSet`? Note: I am NOT using entity framework, so if this is part of it I don't think I can access it.

Comment: What is the type of Property DbContext.Editorials ?

Comment: `Table<Editorials>`

Comment: Then you should use Table<T> instead of DbSet<T>